# What is it called when a new word is replaced by a more familiar one?

Tags: terminology, borrowing

I mean the phenomenon that happens when a language borrows a word, but it gets replaced by a similar-sounding word that is already in the language like from Spanish *'aguacate'* to *'avocado'* or *'echeque mat'* from French to *'check mate'* in English?

Comment: I would just call this "reanalysis". Though the term is a bit broad, you could say, for example: "*Crevisse* was reanalyzed as *cray* + *fish* when it was borrowed into English."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your examples are very different. While Spanish *avocado* might be an instance of folk etymology (history of Spanish is not my area of expertise and I don't feel comfortable commenting on this based on the OED), I will argue English *checkmate* is not.

Not sure why you think one word replaces the other in the case of *checkmate*. If we trust the OED, it says it was borrowed from Old French *eschec , -ek , -eq , eschac*. Loss of Anlaut e- in English in French borrowings is a well-known phonetic change, cf. squire - Old French esquier, escuier; scarf - Old Northern French escarpe etc.

Generally, what you’re trying to describe how a loan word may get changed is known as **assimilation**, which occurs because of the differences in **phonetic/phonological constraints** of the donor and recipient languages (this is **standard** terminology). Sometimes a loan word gets **morphologically reanalyzed** as well. All of those are different ways how a loan word may be integrated (or nativized) in the recipient language; cf. the screenshot below from [Haspelmath 2009](https://www.degruyter.com/view/books/9783110218442/9783110218442.35/9783110218442.35.xml) (in [Loanwords in the World's Languages:
A Comparative Handbook](https://www.degruyter.com/viewbooktoc/product/41172))

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is called an "expressive loan": when a loanword is reanalyzed to fit into the patterns of the new language.

If an unfamiliar, archaic, or foreign word shifts into something *meaningful* in the new language, such as expatriate → ex-patriot or Alzheimer's Disease → old-timer's disease, then that's called an "eggcorn". And if the loanword keeps its original form but is given an incorrect etymology in the new language, that's a "folk etymology". There's significant overlap between these three.

Comment: Never heard of "expressive loans" - just read the wiki article though. I'm not saying this term doesn't exist in linguistics; but I suspect it is **extremely rare**.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're referring to a "folk etymology", where the form or linguistic analysis of a word changes because people don't know the actual history of the word. Hence the original Nahuatl word for avocado "ahuakatl" → Spanish *aguacate* is attested in 1697 as "Avogato pear", subsequently avocato, avigato, avocado. "Avocado" is said to be influenced by Spanish *avocado* "lawyer".

Comment: Ahhh that is most probably it. I thought folk etymology was just a popular (false) etymology of a word or phrase